# Refresh a rendered template when the model is returning store.queryRecord

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a route that displays 5 categories. Each category is intended to only have one child. I created a child route and pass the selected category type id as queryparamter.  In the child route model() I use the parameter with store.queryRecord() to query the backend to either return the record that matches that type OR nothing.  This seems to work fine as long as a record exists.  The problem I am running into is if I select a category that doesn’t have a child record. When nothing is returned from queryRecord the template continues to display the previous data.  I can see the network request completing successfully and it returns an empty array. If I refresh the page the template correctly shows that there is no model data.

I’ve been struggling all day trying to find a way to refresh the template when the model no longer has a record.  I have a feeling I am going at this backwards, I would be grateful for any pointers.

Parent:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
  user: Ember.inject.service('user'),

  model() {
    var user = this.get('user');
    return this.store.findAll('strategic-priority',{ location: user.get('selectedLocationId'), year: user.get('selectedYearId') });
  }
});

HBS
{{#each model as |strategic-priority|}}
    {{#link-to 'priority-area.goal' (query-params priorityArea=strategic-priority.id) class="list-group-item"}} {{strategic-priority.label}} - {{strategic-priority.text}} {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

Child:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  user: Ember.inject.service('user'),
  queryParams: {
    priorityArea: {
      refreshModel: true,
      replace: false,
    }
  },

   model(params) {
     Ember.Logger.debug(params); //I see this is in the console so I know this code is being called each time
     var user = this.get('user');
    return this.store.queryRecord('goal',{ location: user.get('selectedLocationId'), year: user.get('selectedYearId'),priority:  params.priorityArea});
 }
});
```

Comment: You mention child record. So you have a `category` model and you have some relational data, like `hasMany()` items? Do you have a public github link to your project or a jsbin/ember twiddle, where we can see your code?

Comment: To be honest I don’t really understand how to use hasMany. In this case each category in theory hasMany children but I only want to show children that match certain parameters and at first there will be no children until the user creates them. I didn’t think I could create an example because I was using queryRecord but I hadn’t heard of ember twiddle before, I will give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know if this is the correct answer but my workaround was to change the model to use store.query rather than queryRecord. In my template I did a {{#each model as |xx|}} even though I only expected one record.

I was also able to avoid the situation in most cases by using hasMany.  It is a bit cumbersome to gather the data on the backend (at least at my skill level with php and zf2) but in the end it seems to work pretty nice.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to wrap the template that displays a category with `{{#if hasModel}}`. So something like

```
{{#if hasModel}}
  ... your template ...
{{/if}}
```

and then in the controller for your route

```
hasModel: Ember.computed.notEmpty('model')
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but I ran into the same issue. I added a {{log hasModel}} to the template and if I click a link that returns a model from the backend it shows as true. If I click on a link that doesn't load a model it doesn't appear to be evaluated again (doesn't appear in the log).  If I click the browser refresh button and reload the page it correctly logs as false.  It will update to true if I select a link that returns a model but it doesn't work in reverse.